# Cannot reload Cisco device using perl Net::Appliance::Session library

Tags: perl, cisco

I am trying to reboot a Cisco device using net::appliance::session library. But even the code doesn't give en error the device doesn't reboot. This is the two lines I am using:

```
$session->cmd(String => 'Reload',Match => ['/Proceed/'], );
$session->cmd(String => "\n", Match => ['//'],);
```

In the Cisco shell a reload command is given like this:

```
test#reload
Proceed with reload? [confirm]
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

[This thread in the cpan forum](http://cpanforum.com/threads/6937) also tells me to do this way. I think there is a problem with carriage returns and confirm dialogs. Because when I try to create a directory it works fine:

```
$session->cmd(String => 'mkdir',Match => ['/Create dire.*/'] );
$session->cmd(String => 'test',Match => ['//'] );
```

The equivelant of this in Cisco shell:

```
test#mkdir
Create directory filename []? test
Created dir flash:test
```

But when I try to delete this directory which needs a carriage return as confirmation the scripts fails again.

```
$session->cmd(String => 'rmdir asd',Match => ['/Remove directory.*/'] );     
$session->cmd(String => '\n' ,Match => ['/Delete flash.*/'] );
$session->cmd(String => '\n');
```

The equivelant in Cisco is this:

```
test#rmdir test
Remove directory filename [test]? 
Delete flash:test? [confirm]
Removed dir flash:test
```

So I think the problem isn't with reload command. But the problem is sending carriage returns as confirmation. I have tried `\n` `\r` `\n\r` `\r\n` and empty string but they didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Cisco device is case sensitive? In the example you used 'reload' and 'Reload' in the Perl code.

Maybe you could try this:

$session->say('reload');
$session->gather();
$session->say('confirm');
$session->gather();

Comment: Good point. But it didint't work either. Looks like this is not a case sensivity issue. Thanks for the answaer.